# C# nested list storing incorrect values

Tags: c#, list

I am struggling with nested list in c#. I am populating a list with Excel data. For this, I store from all data from a column in subdlist2 and then add it to my main list termsList.

However, at the end when I display the content of my list, values are not those from multiple rows but they are replaced by the values from the last column. Is list content store as reference and not values?

Example: I have 5 rows, with different values, the fifth one values replace all.

```
for (i = 0; i < num_speed; i++)
   {
       lastrow_current = GetLastUsedRow(currentWorksheet, 12 + i * 11);
       for (int j = 0; j < lastrow_current; j++)
       {
           if (currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 12 + i * 11].Value != null)
           {
               if (j == 0)
               {
                   sublist2.Add(currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 13 + i * 11].Value.ToString());
               }
               else
               {
               sublist2.Add(currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 13 + i * 11].Value.ToString());
               }
           }
       }
       termsList.Add(sublist2);
   }
   termsList.Add(sublist2);
   foreach (var sublist3 in termsList)
   {
       foreach (var value in sublist3)
       {
           Console.Write(value);
           Console.Write(' ');
       }
       Console.WriteLine();
   }
```

Comment: May you provide an example of data and output? Anyway, you never create a new instance for `sublist2`, so all members in `termsList` are in fact the same instance of list, which should be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say from your short example. Please update the example so that you include the initialization of the list

But list is indeed a reference object. You should instantiate a new list for each row.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var rows = new List<List<string>>();
for (row = 0; row < maxRow; row++)
{
  var row = new List<string>();
  for (column = 0; column < maxColumn; column++)
  {
    var value = sheet[row, column];
    row.Add(value);
  }
  rows.Add(row);
}
```

Please note that you should give your variables a clear name (not  i,j). Also that you should use temp variables to put you data in:
Don't put currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 13 + i * 11].Value all over the place, but use it once

```
var value = currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 13 + i * 11].Value;
```

And then resuse the value...

Answer (score 0):

There are many things which are confusing in your source code, so first I try to sort it a little bit:

```
// List<List<string>> termsList = the list to fill with nested lists
//        List<string> sublist2 = a list created outside the loop
//                    num_speed = number of columns to process

for (i = 0; i < num_speed; i++)
{
    var currentColumn   = 12 + i * 11; // taken from if (currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 12 + i * 11]
    var differentColumn = 13 + i * 11; // taken from sublist2.Add(currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 13 + i * 11]

    var lastRowOfCurrentColumn = GetLastUsedRow(currentWorksheet, currentColumn);

    for (int j = 0; j < lastRowOfCurrentColumn; j++)
    {
        var currentRow = j + 6; // taken from currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6,

        var currentCell = currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, currentColumn];
        var differentCell = currentWorksheet.Cells[currentRow, anotherColumn];

        // here you are checking if the cell has a value ...
        if (currentCell.Value != null)
// was  if (currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 12 + i * 11].Value != null)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                // ... but here ...
                sublist2.Add(differentCell.Value.ToString());
        // was  sublist2.Add(currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 13 + i * 11].Value.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                // ... and here you are adding a value from a cell
                // out of a different column to the list
                sublist2.Add(differentCell.Value.ToString());
        // was  sublist2.Add(currentWorksheet.Cells[j + 6, 13 + i * 11].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    // Here you are adding the same list to the parent list
    // again and again for every row ...
    termsList.Add(sublist2);
}

// ... and outside the loop you are adding that list again to the parent
termsList.Add(sublist2);
```

So besides of checking the value of one cell, but using the value from a different cell to add to the list, you are using the same list at every row.

To have a separate list for each row and also to use the actual checked column, you have to change your code like that:

```
for (int j = 0; j < lastRowOfCurrentColumn; j++)
{
    var listForRow = new List<string>();
// ...
                listForRow.Add(currentCell.Value.ToString());
// ...
    termsList.Add(listForRow);
}
```

And remove the superfluous addition of a nested list outside of the loop.